TypeScript type union on function params
I've created a type union so that I can dynamically send arguments to my function, and it should infer if the value is string or string[], and also if onChange should take string or string[] as an argument:
interface BaseProps {
label?: string;
}

interface MultiProps extends BaseProps {
  isMultiselect: true;
  value: string[];
  onChange: (value: string[]) => void;
}

interface SingleProps extends BaseProps {
  isMultiselect?: false;
  value: string;
  onChange: (value: string) => void;
 }

type Props = MultiProps | SingleProps;

const example = ({ onChange, value }: Props) => onChange(value);

but there, on the last line, when I try to call onChange, it doesn't work. I get the type of onChange to be onChange: (value: string[] & string) => void.
I don't understand why, and what should I do to get the behavior I wanted.
I would like to have onChange with the type signature like onChange: (value: string[] | string) => void, and to have it inferred based on isMultiselect, or if value is string or array.

TS doesn't directly support correlated unions as described in ms/TS#30581. It only supports generics, as shown in this playground link. That might be enough for your use case, as long as you don't actually need a union there. Do you need a union? You haven't shown a use case where you call example. Please respond or [edit] to clarify.

I did a minimal example, but this is actually a React component. I want to be able to pass props like stateand setState - as string or array - without the need to type cast (setState(value as string[]). I see the point of the generic, but it was not exactly what I needed.

To satisfy TS sometimes JS should be really ugly, for a quick fix you can benefit the tagged union:
const example = ({ onChange, value, isMultiselect}: Props) => isMultiselect ? onChange(value) : onChange(value);

